# Почему нет доступа к полям MyIterator?

Tags: c++, классы

Я пишу вторую версию вставки в map, где нужно передавать ещё и итератор, помимо вставляемой пары, то есть пишу аналог такой вставки:

```
std::map<char,int>::iterator it = mymap.begin();
  mymap.insert (it, std::pair<char,int>('b',300));  // max efficiency inserting
  mymap.insert (it, std::pair<char,int>('c',400));  // no max efficiency inserting
```

В этом примере из STL, мне не понятно,зачем они передают итератор и называют это эффективной вставкой. Итератор же и так будет пробегать значения , пока не наткнётся на нужную пару. Что в этом эффективного?

```
template<class T,class R>
class Map 
{


public:
    Map();
    ~Map();
    R& operator[](T index)
    {
        return tree.searchOperator(index);
    }
    class MyIterator : public iterator<bidirectional_iterator_tag, RBTNode<T, R>>
    {
        friend class Map;
        public:
        MyIterator(RBTNode<T, R> *it)
        {
            second = it->Element.second;
            first = it->Element.first;
            temp = it;
        }
        MyIterator()
        {

        }
        MyIterator& operator=(const MyIterator& it) 
        {
            first = it.first;
            second = it.second;
            temp = it.temp;
            return (*this);
        }
        MyIterator& operator*()
        {

            return (*this);
        }
        MyIterator(const MyIterator& source)
        {
            first = source.first;
            second = source.second;
            temp = source.temp;
            /*temp->left = source.temp->left;
            temp->right = source.temp->right;
            temp->parent = source.temp->parent;
            temp->Element.first = source.temp->Element.first;
            temp->Element.second = source.temp->Element.second;
            temp->color = source.temp->color;*/
        }

        MyIterator operator++(int) 
        {//Post ++
            int j = 0;
            if (temp->right != NULL)
            {
                temp = temp->right;
            }
            if (temp->parent != NULL)//если root
            {
                temp = temp->parent;
            }


            first = temp->Element.first;
            second = temp->Element.second;
            return *this;
        }
        MyIterator *operator->() 
        {
            // 
            return (this);
        }

    public:
        T first;
        R second;
    private:
        RBTNode<T, R>* temp;
    };
    MyIterator begin()
    {
        RBTNode<T, R>* pt = tree.f_begin();
        MyIterator temp(pt);

        return temp;
    }
    pair<MyIterator, bool> insert(const std::pair<T,R> tempo)// first insert function
    {
        std::pair<MyIterator, bool> returnable;
        if (!tree.search(tempo.first))// проверка на уникальность
        {
            //RBTNode<T, R> tempnode;

            tree.insert(tempo.first, tempo.second);
            MyIterator ret(tree.search(tempo.first));//конструктор,чтобы знать ноду
            returnable.first = ret;
            returnable.second = 1;
            return returnable;
        }
        else 
        {
            MyIterator ret(tree.search(tempo.first));//конструктор,чтобы знать ноду
            returnable.first = ret;
            returnable.second = 0;
            return returnable;
        }


        //return ret;
    }

    MyIterator insert(MyIterator& it,  const std::pair<T, R> tempo)//second insertation function
    {


    }

private:
      RBTree<T,R> tree;

    //RBTNode<T, R> tempnode;
};

template <class T,class R>
Map<T, R>::Map() {


}
template <class T, class R>
Map<T,R>::~Map()
{

}
```

Вот в этой функции мне почему-то не доступны поля it. Как сделать их доступными?

```
MyIterator insert(MyIterator& it,  const std::pair<T, R> tempo)//second insertation function
        {


              it-> // не работает, хоть и оператор -> перегружен
              it. // не работает доступ к полям(хотя бы public first и second)

        }
```

Comment: А зачем делать класс Map другом, если он итак содержит внутри себя этот вложенный класс? Странно, что у тебя operator->() возвращает указатель, мне кажется, что это нарушает логику работы этого оператора, он ведь по сути был создан для упрощения синтаксиса (*pointer).member.

Comment: @Πανμέτρονάριστον, другом я его сделал, чтобы попытаться избавиться от этой проблемы - не помогло, т.к. доступа к операторам всё равно нет

Comment: вангую, там проблема с разрешением контекста или с неоднозначностью (класс то шаблонный).

Comment: @Πανμέτρονάριστον, как интерпретировать "неоднозначность и разрешение контекста" в смысле классов?

Comment: А ты не пробовал тупо объявить данные-члены выше, чем функции-члены? Обычно так и делается ведь... Может проблема в этом. Типа предварительного объявления нет.

Comment: При наличии перегруженного оператора `->`, в типе данных, возвращаемом из оператора `->`, будет вызван этот перегруженный оператор, и так до бесконечности.  Соберите члены first+second в отдельную струтктуру и возвращайте указатель на неё.

Comment: @Chorkov, перегрузка -> работает нормально, уже тестировал, возникает ворнинг как опасность рекурсии, но пока всё исправно

Comment: @Πανμέτρονάριστον, то есть написать public:T first;R second;  выше, чем методы класса?

Comment: @Chorkov, ну да. Вообще, не правильно так определять класс. У тебя все эти методы будут inline. И предварительного объявления нет. Если один метод используется внутри другого, но не определён раньше, то будет ошибка. Хотя... Это шаблон...

Comment: @Πανμέτρονάριστον, не прокатило(

Comment: Во первых передавать итератор при вставке является эффективной, потому что далеко не всегда этот итератор является итератором на начало. Иногда мы  знаем , что можно искать не с начала, а с  узла, на который указывает некий итератор. , во вторых  в  C++17 запрещены крайне редкие возможности стандартной библиотеки, и в их числе std::iterator, от чего вы пытаетесь наследовать свой итератор. Определите итератор с нуля(без наследования) потом можно будет говорить о других ошибках

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ссылка на русскую документацию: https://ru.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/insert

Смотрим 3-4 перегрузку

> Сложность
>
> 3-4) Амортизированная константа, если вставка происходит в позицию прямо после хинта. Иначе — логарифмическая по размеру контейнера.
>   (до C++11)
>
> 3-4) Амортизированная константа, если вставка происходит в позицию прямо перед хинтом. Иначе — логарифмическая по размеру контейнера.

Получается, что такое использование будет эффективно, если вы знаете куда будет вставлен элемент.

Теперь по поводу недоступности:

```
MyIterator insert(MyIterator& it,  const std::pair<T, R> tempo)
        {


              it-> // не работает, хоть и оператор -> перегружен
              it. // не работает доступ к полям(хотя бы public first и second)

        }
```

С чего вы взяли что нет доступа. Доступ есть и все должно работать.
Предполагаю, что IntelliSense просто не "подсказывает" вам поля. Это происходит из-за шаблонности класса MyIterator. Если вручную написать - все будет работать.

Comment: да, так и оказалось